# How to autopostback textchange after get return value from telerik windows

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have textbox with event textchanged and autopostback is true, when textbox get value from return value dialog telerik event textchange not working (not postback whereas value text was change)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume the textbox is getting the text from the Telerik control and that it's working?

Is your viewstate enabled?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx

Also, you might want to check this thread out:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1123520.aspx/2/10

Depending on how you have your code written (which is impossible to tell because you haven't given any) you will probably have to TAB out of the textbox in order for the update to happen. You will most likely need to use some javascript to help you here.

Comment: Thanks.. but i just add __doPostBack('textbox',''); and now work